# Execute external swift code inside a macOS app

Tags: swift, macos

I have an external swift 5 file (just function code no UI) that will be fetched daily from a server. I want to embed the code in my running MacOS app so that the code in the external swift file will be executed when the user presses a button. I´m not sure if this is even possible.

The Idea is something like this:

External swift script:

```
import SwiftUI

func sayHello() {

print("Hi")

}

func newCode() {

// some fancy code

}
```

The script contains one or two functions (always the same name) that should be called from the buttons (just for simplicity).
The code inside the functions will be always completely different e.g.: some processing of data or changing settings in my app via the app api.

It would be great if there might be a swift solution, other ways I must use a shell script that is executed with Pipe() but I´m not that good in shell programming so I want to avoid it.

The Apple Shortcut app allows user to "program" their code by drag n drop, so maybe this is way to do so, but I don't no how their logic behind this works and if this is similar to my problem.

Comment: Sounds like using some type of remote config might work better.  But without seeing some kind of example of how the code might change it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: @MwcsMac A code logic could look something like this: 1. Download data from the URL 2. Process data 3. Send data to the app via the API and compress the output or convert it to CSV 4. Upload data to the URL. Another logic would be 1. As above 2. As above 3. Send data to the app via the API and do something with the output, send the data back to the app and compare the output 4. Save data sets locally - maybe that helps understanding my project - so the workflow will always be different, that's why I want to use an external script.

Comment: A script would be fine but you can't use swift code